# How do I get the FreeTextTable.Rank via Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, full-text-search, freetext

I'm able to get a list of records using FreeTextTable in Entity Framework as follows:

```
var EventsSqlWhere = $"SELECT top 200 * FROM FreeTextTable(Events, *, {0}, 200) as t INNER JOIN Events u on u.Id = t.[KEY] ORDER BY t.[RANK] desc";

listEvents = await dbContext.Events
        .FromSqlRaw(EventsSqlWhere, Query)
        .Where(e => (! e.Private) && (e.Enabled))
        .Include(e => e.Signups)!
        .ThenInclude(s => s.User)
        .ToListAsync();
```

But nothing I try can also get me the t.RANK column. How can I get that? Either as a `[NotMapped]` column in the `Event` object or the returned list objects are a `tuple<Event,Rank>`. Or anything.